# Codefresh: How to use assume role in docker registry while adding ecr?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr, assume-role, codefresh

Codefresh takes only 2 params:
**Access key**
**Secret key**

I've got assume role to work on local but it requires aws config file etc

Any ideas how to use assume role to add ecr to docker registry in Codefresh?
Or how to get **Access key** and **Secret key** from assume role?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or how to get Access key and Secret key from assume role?

Generally you use [STS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) service for that. The service has [assume-role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html) API call.  The call:

> Returns a set of **temporary security credentials** that you can use to access AWS resources that you might not normally have access to.

However, the credentials (access key ID, secret access key, and a security token) that you get are **temporary**. They can last from 15 min to max 12 hours (depending on the role settings).

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that one. Temporary will not work since we need to integrate it for good

Comment: @Sergio13  I see. I think that you should create IAM user, with just the permissions which Codefresh requires. With this, you will have permanent credentials.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it is the only option. Thanks a lot!!